# How to convert the given dictionary to dataframe with keys as column name?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I obtained a dictionary variable by reading a `.mat` file,which contain data in the format

```
   {'a': array([[0.75]]),

   'b': array([[(array([[359.98694593],
                [180.        ],
                [210.        ],
                [192.        ],
                [345.48700736],
                [340.84307348],
                [301.        ],
                [333.65735726],
                [258.        ],
                [185.        ],
                [350.80167438],
                [306.        ],
                [340.84307348]]), array([[50.00000073],
                [50.        ],
                [55.        ],
                [71.        ],
                [57.36137109],
                [68.01410104],
                [52.        ],
                [74.23729974],
                [65.        ],
                [64.        ],
                [68.50496863],
                [74.        ],
                [68.01410104]]), array([[ -90.008391  ],
                [ -55.        ],
                [ -89.99      ],
                [  -7.        ],
                [ -95.16436518],
                [ -90.80783483],
                [ -54.        ],
                [-127.25235458],
                [ -94.        ],
                [-129.        ],
                [  12.91192521],
                [ 174.        ],
                [ -90.80783483]]))                      ]],
       dtype=[('s', 'O'), ('d', 'O'), ('r', 'O')]),

   'c': array([[(array([[343.40093986],
                [160.44620001]]), array([[64.0663043 ],
                [62.87984286]]), array([[-86.7123111 ],
                [-93.32188837]]))                      ]],
       dtype=[('s', 'O'), ('d', 'O'), ('r', 'O')]),

   'd': array([[0.66213805]]),

   'e': array([[(array([[330.59152333]]), array([[86.9846138]]))]],
       dtype=[('a', 'O'), ('p', 'O')]),

   'f': array([[(array([[161.96185501]]), array([[2.95631043]]))]],
       dtype=[('a', 'O'), ('p', 'O')]),


   'g': array([[(array([[71.9312074]]), array([[0.59342796]]))]],
       dtype=[('a', 'O'), ('p', 'O')])}
```

I would like to convert this dictionary to a dataframe with its keys as column names.
Is there any specific function for unpack the array which contains more arrays ?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` will generate what you need with little to no change to your current data.

Comment: I tried that one but it gives me an error `ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: try to transpose or .flatten()/ravel() every value of the dictionary first